# OpenCL on Radeon RX 5700XT slow

Tags: 18.04, performance, radeon, opencl

Running jobs on OpenCL in Ubuntu 18.04 is about 10x slower than running them on Windows on a Radeon RX 5700 XT.

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 HWE and amdgpu 19.50 with --headless and --opencl=legacy,pal

The OpenCL kernels load and run, they're just sluggish.

I've also tried upgrading the Linux kernel to 5.3.18 with no apparent improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I reached out to the Radeon Linux driver maintainers and they indicated that this patch improves Radeon RX 5700XT performance: [46203a508f64b4bfa150a9d25eab1dc891e7e650](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/46203a508f64b4bfa150a9d25eab1dc891e7e650)

This change only appears in 5.5 kernels. I can confirm that kernel 5.5rc7 (latest on https://kernel.ubuntu.com/ at time of writing) can improve OpenCL performance by more than 10x.

Ubuntu 18.04.3 doesn't include kernel 5.5 yet, so to get this improvement, you'll need to install it yourself. Go to the Ubuntu kernel page, choose the 5.5 kernel version you want, find your architecture, choose low-latency or generic, and download linux-headers-..._all.deb, linux-headers-..._<arch>.deb, linux-image-..._<arch>.deb, linux-modules-..._<arch>.deb

Run:

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-..._all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-..._<arch>.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-image-..._<arch>.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-modules-..._<arch>.deb
```

Reboot to use the new kernel.

Comment: Worked a treat for me this.  Many thanks, I spent ages trying to find the answer till I found this. :-)